# Blank screen after a minute in newer Linux OSes

Tags: amd-graphics

I've searched for this on Google quite a few times, and also tried a few fixes for Ubuntu from StackOverflow, but the problem isn't completely solved.

My laptop has an AMD CPU (A10-8700P) and AMD GPU (R7 M360). Whenever I try to install ANY newer Linux OS, like Ubuntu, Mint, AntergOS, Elementary, and even Solus, after a minute into the setup, the screen goes blank (black). The computer's still on, and powers off when I press the power button, so it's a graphics problem.

I've installed Ubuntu with nomodeset before, but it lagged a lot, and the next boot had some problem (I don't remember, but I guess it was that the nomodeset thingy had to be set again at each boot for the display to work).

Is there any fix for it? Do I have to live with Windows for the rest of my laptop's life?
Also, why does the display stop working only after a minute, why's everything fine before it?

EDIT:
Output for `lspci -s -v $(lspci | grep VGA | cut -d" " -f 1)`:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Carriz
o (rev c5) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 80b5
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at d00000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f08000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=256]
    Memory at ff700000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in user: amdgpu
    Kernel module: amdgpu
```

Comment: _“I guess it was that the nomodeset thingy had to be set again at each boot”_ It depends on where you set it. You can set it temporarily in GRUB runtime environment, or permanently in GRUB configuration files.

Comment: I set it in the GRUB runtime environment probably (sorry, I'm a newbie). But the main problem I have with it is performance: it lags a lot

Comment: You don't have to live with Windows. You can user Ubuntu and describe any issues you have with the environment with the Ubuntu community for assistance. That is the same thing that Windows do with Windows... or any other OSes. What is the graphics adapter you have in your computer? Please update your question to include the output of: `lspci  -v -s  $(lspci | grep VGA | cut -d" " -f 1)?`

Comment: @L.D.James Edited with the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your **nomodeset** a default to **allow proper booting** while you work with configuring video adapter with the proper drivers.  Edit your `/etc/default/grub` file and added `nomodeset` to the grub commandline:

Change from:

```
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Change to:

```
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

After editing the `/etc/default/grub` file you have to update grub to make it in effect:

```
$ sudo apt update-grub
```

**For the graphic problem use the provided drivers for your graphics adapter.**

There are links to the Drivers recommended by the Ubuntu Community:
[RadeonDriver - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver)
[AMDGPU-PRO Driver for Linux Release Notes](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx)

After installing new drivers use `additional drivers` from **System Settings** to pick the best.

Comment: Thanks for the nomodeset solution. Though my real problem is performance - even minimal things like minimizing or maximizing a window lag. I've, on AntergOS, seen that it uses amdgpu drivers, which do the same work-for-a-minute-then-blank dance. I've decided to not go with Ubuntu and give AntergOS a chance, with fglrx.
I'll try something called Oibaf's drivers too, first.

Comment: Use the second link and change your video drivers.  The having the best video drivers will improve  the performance you describe which is sluggish by not being able to maximize the GPU hardware.

Comment: The page doesn't show support for my GPU, R7 M360. Should I still try it?